# PDO - getting column count on a prepared statement, is it possible?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, metadata, calculated-columns

I'm trying to refine my database access classes to help at the time of processing form data. What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

1. add an SQL query to my connection object.
2. classify the SQL query by its commands and arguments.
3. use the classification data to automatically add the `required` attribute to a given form input tag (and, optionally, insert a given or corresponding RegEx for advanced matching).
4. add a session-driven temporary object holding the form members to check for both completeness and compliancy with a given set of rules or matches.
5. execute the SQL query once all the given requirements are satisfied.

Then, the way to proceed (in my actual code) is like this:

```
if (!empty($data = \Helpers\Forms\getData($_POST))) {
    if (!empty($rules = \Helpers\Forms\getRules($_POST))) {
        if ($data->isCompliant($rules)) {
            // rest continues here...
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I've got steps 1, 3 and 5 fully completed. I got steps 2 and 4 just partially implemented because I need a way to do a metadata scan on a given prepared SQL query and that's where I'm a bit lost.

According to the PDO manual, the `columnCount()` method doesn't provide an accurate result until the `execute()` method is called.

However, the execute method actually executes the query and I don't want to do it because if it's a SELECT query, it would actually be ok but not for a INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE or any other kind of query.

So my question is... is there any way to get the column count for a given SQL query without executing it? Or maybe... is there a way to perform a dummy execution of a given SQL query to obtain this column count value?

Comment: it's a query. YOU'RE the one specifying the columns to be returned, so you should know how many you're requesting in the first place. Perhaps you mean row count?

Comment: Of course I know the number of columns specified at declaration time, but that's not practical, as I want (ideally) a full automated system where I declare the query ONCE and then pass its metadata to both the elements I create within a given form and the form validation code in the other end. Could I simplify the schema by providing the fields myself? Sure. But that would deprive me of providing full field metadata (and, thus, knowing if a given field is required or not, if the field is of a certain type, if it should have a validation RegEx or not, etc.), and I would like to avoid that.